# What is an efficient way to inject j/s variables into a reusable block of HTML without mixing the two in a j/s file?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Basically, I have an autocomplete function to help users select an item.  When they select an item, a series of variables relating to the item are saved.  Once they click 'add', the variables are then injected into an HTML template, and the HTML template is injected into the DOM.  My question is, how can I do this without having to mix my HTML code with the j/s code i.e. `var example = "<div id='" + divId + "'></div>";` (etc.) I hope the question is clear enough.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, I believe that there isn't a way to separate your HTML code. You could use DOM manipulation if you wish to.

Comment: You could use pure DOM functions, like `createElement` etc. That may get fairly verbose, but it has the upside of working on arbitrary XML documents rather than just tag soups. Or use a framework like jquery that combines string parsing and proper DOM handling.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into [jQuery Templates](http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/)?  It's basically client-side data binding, which seems like what you are trying to do.

For example, you can do stuff like this..

Assuming you have a list of Song objects, defined as:

```
var song = {
  title : 'Purple Rain',
  artist : 'Prince'
};
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Template definition -->
<script id="tmpl_songList" type="text/html">
  <li>
    <a>
        <span>${title}</span>
        <span>${artist}</span>
    </a>
  </li>
</script>

<!-- HTML container to host data-bound list -->
<ul id="song_list"></ul>
```

JS:

```
// bind data (songList) and append to HTML container.
$.tmpl($('#tmpl_songList'), songList).appendTo($('#song_list'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var example = $("<div />").attr("id",divId);
```

But when you have a lot of nested tags it can be tedious to create each element, in those cases i mix them up.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var myID = "id";
var myText = "Some Text"
$('<div/>', {
    id: myID,
    html: myText
  }).appendTo('body');
```

You can add more properties, if needed.

On the other hand, if your manipulations are complex, use a template engine. It is easier to maintain.